# Angular: Iterate over Array of objects

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have some troubles with iterating over an array of objects. In each object I have a name, but some objects have their own arrays. The structure looks like this:

```
const arr = [{name:1},{name:2}, {name: '1234', childrenId: 'id', children: [{name:3},{name:4}]}]
```

And I need display it in this way
expected result - list of the names:

- 1
- 2
- 1234
- 3
- 4

I've tried this approach

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of arr;">
   {{ item.name }}
  <ng-container *ngIf="item.childrenId">
     <ng-container *ngFor="let child of item.children">  {{ child.name }} </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

But it displays not in exactly way I need, there is some overlap of children on regular items:
[image: Pic]

EDIT: thanks everyone, I decided to change the array structure to more linear. It works fine now

Comment: what does it display?

Comment: @nosTa, I've added a pic

Comment: do you have a css file configured?

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize the html list-element instead of doing ng-containers. Also as @nosTa mentions in the comments it looks like you have some extra css included that is messing with the layout so its hard to reproduce, but I've created a stackblitz that you can take a look at here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9rjnpr?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display it in a list you can use the HTML list elements ul / li. In your approach you get the data but not displayed correctly. When using ul / li elements it should work as expected.

```
<ul>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of arr;">
        <li>{{ item.name }}</li>
        <ng-container *ngIf="item.childrenId">
            <li *ngFor="let child of item.children">
                {{ child.name }}
            </li>
        </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
</ul>
```

[image: working code]